# AJAX/page refresh kills JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making an A/B test (Injecting code onto a page) to increase the images of products in your shopping cart.

When you select a different shipping method - the whole table appears to be refreshed.

and my code will only execute the first time.

So when i select a different shipping method the second time. my code is lost.

Except the  tags stay.

You'll need to have a random product in your cart to see it first.

```js
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('img.item-img').each(function() {
    var str      = $(this).attr('src'),
        arr      = str.split("?");
  query  = "?hei=200&wid=200&op_sharpen=1"
    $(this).attr('src', arr[0] + query);

});



  
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('tr').each(function() {
  var desc = $('td.description', this).html() 
  $('td.image', this).append(desc);
  $('td.description', this).remove();
});
  $("table#shopping-cart-items tr td.image").after($('<td id="clearSpace"></td>'));

});
});

  

  </script>




<script>
  
  
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('div.shippingOpt').click(function() {
  
  
   window.setTimeout(function(){  

 
 
  $('img.item-img').each(function() {
    var str      = $(this).attr('src'),
        arr      = str.split("?");
  query  = "?hei=200&wid=200&op_sharpen=1"
    $(this).attr('src', arr[0] + query);

});

 
   $('tr').each(function() {
  var desc = $('td.description', this).html() 
  $('td.image', this).append(desc);
  $('td.description', this).remove();
});
                     
  $("table#shopping-cart-items tr td.image").after($('<td id="clearSpace"></td>'));
     
          }, 1000);           
                    });
});



  </script>
```

```css
<style>
    .checkoutBasket table.cart-container td.image img { width:200px; height:auto;}
  
 #clearSpace  {padding: 0 0 0 15px;}
</style>
```

Comment: Use `$('div.shippingOpt').on('click', function(){{....});`

Answer (score -4):

Please use the following code:

```
$('div.shippingOpt').on('click', function(){{...});
```

Comment: Now it doesn't work when i click an option.

Comment: @Quentin - I don't see this as being a "Direct copy and paste of an existing question" also seeing as how the answer(s) haven't helped me yet.

Comment: .live seems to work as i have 1.8.3 running.